# PHP - session is not being destroyed in Chromium

Tags: php, session

I've got really weird problem on my Chromium.
There are:

1) Simple login that checks username/pass and if everything's correct it sets session variables and redirects user:

```
    if(md5($_POST['password'])==$password) {
         $_SESSION['username']="admin";
         header('Location: index2.php');
    } else {
        echo "Wrong username or password!";
    }
```

2) Simple session check at the top of every page

```
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['username']!="admin")
        header('Location: index.php');
```

3) Logout:

```
   session_start();

   $_SESSION['username']="";
   unset($_SESSION['username']);

   session_destroy();

   header('Refresh: 2; URL = index.php');
   echo 'Thank you for logging out';
```

It works fine on Firefox. It even works fine on Chromium if I restart the browser after logout. But if I keep the window open I could still access all the documents, as it says that $_SESSION['username'] has not been unset in logout.php!
That looks like some kind of cache, but there should be no cache when it comes to sessions, shouldn't it?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) as well.

> The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently
>   registered.

```
<?php
session_start();

// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy();

//redirect user
header("Location:index.php");
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately didn't help ((